# PHP Login Keeps Returning Invalid User

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty sure I have this coded correctly, but I'm not entirely sure. This is for a simple login form, and I keep getting "Invalid User" returned whenever I try to login.

I'm checking MySQL database, and the entry is there. Here is my code in log.php:

```
<?php
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {
    $conn = mysql_connect("host","username","password"); // your       MySQL connection data
    $db = mysql_select_db("database"); //put your database name in here 
    $name = $_POST['user'];
    $q_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($q_user) == 1) {

        $query = mysql_query("                                      SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE       login='$name'");
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if($_POST['pwd'] == $data['password']) { 
            session_register("name");
            header("Location: index.html"); // success page. put the URL you want 
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Wrong Password'));
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Invalid User'));
        exit;
    }
}

// if the session is not registered
if(session_is_registered("name") == false) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: The instant you have `mysql_` anywhere, it’s not coded correctly. Use PDO and prepared statements! Stop me from logging in with the username `nonexistent' UNION ALL SELECT 'admin' AS username, '' AS password;--`. And hash your passwords (using a **password hash**).

Comment: Not exactly to your qeustion, but for failed logins, you should never tell the person if they got the password wrong or the user wrong, otherwise an attacker can sniff your user names.

Comment: So is your password saved as plain text in the database??

Comment: @Tim: Though most registration pages let you do that either way (even the ones with captchas), and if profiles are public, it’s definitely no issue.

Comment: You should ABSOLUTELY NOT pass login parameters via GET.

Comment: Why are you doing the same query twice? `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login='$name'`. You shoud also be checking the password in there `WHERE` clause of your SQL statement, not in your code.

Comment: @minitech I actually never thought of that

Comment: @MikeBrant: Good advice, but it’s passed using POST here.

Comment: and it is using unsanitized data in queries. Not a `mysql_real_escape_string` in sight.

Comment: @Tim `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated as minitech hinted at in the first comment.

Comment: @Mike yeah, but so is `mysql_` anything, which the OP is also using. If they are going to insist on using `mysql_query` then they had better be using `mysql_real_escape_string` along with it.

Comment: For the purpose of this login form, I'm just using phpMyAdmin. I tried following all steps in the various tutorials online, and being quite new to PHP, and databases, I'm a little confused by some of the solutions in the comments. I apologize.

Comment: @LoganDeyo they're not solutions. They're trying to get you to not code in a way that makes you vulnerable to various attacks.

Comment: @minitech Well I just lookied at the first conditionwhere it is looking faor `$_GET['login']`. One should not be trying to mix these value.  Mybe using `$_POST['login']` will make things work correctly.

Comment: @Mike I'm aware of that. But for the purpose of this login form, and using it only locally, I'm just trying to understand the reason behind the Invalid User problem. I'm well aware of the various attacks that could come my way based on the way this form was created.

Comment: @MikeBrant I don't think that is good advice. There are reasons to mix get and post data.

Comment: @LoganDeyo: phpMyAdmin doesn’t have anything to do with it. PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Tim There could be from time to time, but my guess is the OP would be best served trying to get his form working using exclusively POST before trying to delve into the world of what things should normally be passed via GET (typically things you want user to be able to navigate to/bookmark and get consistent outcome) vs. POST (cases where you try to collect data from the user and/or change data in some persisted storage like a database).

Comment: @MikeBrant Ok, fair enough

Comment: Ok well the problem is that the first query is either coming up empty, or you have duplicate user names. verify using `var_dump` that the user name is being received properly and that you actually have exactly one row with that username.

Comment: @Tim Assuming there was a problem with that since it returned with:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'var_dump' at line 1"

Comment: no, `var_dump` is a php function, I meant to make sure the php script received the data you are expecting. Then look in your database with phpMyAdmin to see if there is **exactly** one row with that username

Comment: @Tim I know I sound extremely stupid, but how do I go about doing that? Sorry for my newness.

Comment: comment out the `header` line for invalid user and write `var_dump($name);` it will print something out on the page. Make sure it is what you expect it to be for the username. To check your data do the query: `SELECT login FROM USERS WHERE 1` and print out the results. The user name you are expecting should show up, and it should show up only once. If it **is** there only once, but the case is different(has an upper case letter or some such), tell me that also.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your implementation:

1. You're still using `mysql_` functions; those are deprecated in favour of either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).
2. Because of #1 you're not using prepared statements either.
3. Because of #2 and the fact that you're not properly escaping your variables in SQL your code is vulnerable against SQL injection attacks.
4. You're storing passwords in plain text. You should use [password hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php); if you're not using 5.5, you can use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) instead.
5. The use of `session_register()` is deprecated; you should use the superglobal `$_SESSION` instead.

Here's an example you could use to accomplish the same thing:

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

if ($action == 'login') {
    $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ]);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$user]);

    if (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
        header("Location: index.html"); // success page. put the URL you want 
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Invalid User or password'));
    }
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Very thorough.

Comment: Since the OP is having problems with the wrong branch being taken in the conditional, there must be something screwy going on with his data. This is an excellent post though.

Comment: @Tim Sure, but I'd rather he has problems with this code than his own :)

Comment: +1 for demonstration of the GREATLY underutilized `filter_input()` function.

Comment: (Except none of the sanitizing filters but this should ever be used)

Comment: @minitech Very interesting. Can you provide a link to support that since I've never heard that before?

Comment: @Mike: Escape on output, validate input. *Filtering* input in the way PHP’s built-in monolith does it is almost always wrong.

Comment: @minitech If there are rules on usernames or passwords, you should as much as possible try to sanitize against that :) as with other things in php, its filtering functions are also used for validation heh

Comment: @Jack: Why? If there are rules on usernames or passwords, check them when whoever is signing up. It won’t be in the database anyways, and PDO makes providing input safe. If you like the safer fuzzy feeling, separate out the checks and run the same function in both places. Stripping HTML (the *obviously* named `SANITIZE_STRING` does that), for example, is usually wholly inappropriate.

Comment: Wait… doesn’t `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` not even do anything by default?

Comment: @minitech No real reason I suppose, unless you like being strict ... and yes, as the name implies, `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` does nothing but return a string or null (if not present).